# Java Applet: Socket fails to connect

Tags: java, sockets, applet

We have a problem with creating a new Socket using java applet.

The server is recently updated (Sun Solaris 9 to CentOS 5) (32 to 64 bit).  And one of the applet stopped working (specifically on):

```
public ... extends Applet{
...
PORT = 8888;
...
s = new Socket(this.getCodeBase().getHost(),PORT) 
}
```

The url is correct. The stack trace tells me that:

```
The connection is time out;
```

This applet worked fine before the update, so we suspect this is something to do with the update (Java might be updated too, we are not sure).

This is a little perplexing: could anyone tell us what the problem could be and how should we solve it?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the firewall settings? Maybe it is just dropping incoming packages on port 8888?

Comment: I am pretty green on the whole server thing - how could I check the firewall settings and change it? thanks!

Comment: CentOS uses `iptables`. You can get a list of defined rules with the following command: `iptables --line-numbers -n -L`. There might be a GUI too...

Comment: OK I will check on that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Might be due to server is too busy. Also might be due to some firewalls. Your code is fine. You need to work around your network infrastructure.